# Can I add a number to a field when a date field is updated in SharePoint 2010 Foundation

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have a due date field in a share point list. Sometimes, people need to extend the due date from its original one. I was asked to create another field named 'Version'. Whenever the due date of a list item is updated,a value of 1 needs to be added to this Version field . So, if the due date field has been updated 2 times, then Version field shows 2. Is this possible to do in Share point 2010. Any help is much appreciated. I am a beginner in Share point.

I have seen a similar question [here](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000ZffYAAS)! but it is for Salesforce

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature called version history. After you [enable versioning in list settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-and-configure-versioning-for-a-list-or-library-1555d642-23ee-446a-990a-bcab618c7a37#OfficeVersion=2010), you shall be able [view the version history](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-the-version-history-of-an-item-or-file-in-a-list-or-library-53262060-5092-424d-a50b-c798b0ec32b1#ID0EAAGAAA=2010).

If you do not have this feature in SharePoint 2010 Foundation, you may need to use a SharePoint designer workflow to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer. However, the purpose of my 'Version' field was to export the data into an excel sheet and show others how many times the due date for that particular item has been extended. I will try the workflow method you mentioned.